# Appointments across different daylight saving time areas are silently modified

Tags: google-calendar

When I create an appointment at 9:00 in NYC (US Eastern timezone), my guest in London (GMT) has to attend it at 14:00 his time.
However, the US and Britain switch to daylight saving time at different moments (2015-03-08 vs 2015-03-29).
This means that my guest has to attend the meeting at 13:00 his time for the next 3 weeks.

Google handles this seamlessly, maybe even *too* seamlessly: my guest is *not* notified that his meeting has shifted by an hour.

This is not very good (he may have other appointments not affected by the DST lunacy).  Ideally, the user should be notified whenever an appointment's local time changes.

**What can be done about it?**

Comment: Interesting problem - timezones/DST can be troublesome. However, I imagine the answer in this case is just to make sure they check their calendar and set appropriate reminders. Just a thought... if the user has "Receive an update when someone changes an event" checked under "Edit notifications" (default false) do they get notified in this instance?! Is this considered a "change"?

Comment: @w3d: where do I find `Edit notifications`?

Comment: Gear menu > settings > Calendars "tab" > for each calendar there is an "Edit notifications" link under which there are various notifications that can be set for when events are "Changed", "Cancelled", etc. Although I think they are all "off" by default.